# Quit button for Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

my game starts with SplashActivity.And 3 secs later MenuActivity is starting by intent automatically.there is a button for quiting in MenuActivity.When I pressed it,finish() is running and the game is coming back to SplashActivity not exiting from full game.I want: When I press button,the game totaly exit.What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you leave your SplashActivity by calling your MenuActivity, be sure and call finish() after the call to your MenuActivity